# elasticsearch not receiving from localhost

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, logstash-configuration, elasticsearch-5

I run logstash(192.168.56.100) and elasticsearch(192.168.56.100) on same host, but elasticsearch just create index and not receiving data. And I try run logstash(192.168.56.101) on different host, and  elasticsearch(192.168.56.100) can receiving data. this my elasticsearch and logstash config

example data : 12345~78904

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/tmp/tmp.log"
  }
}

filter {
    grok {
     match => ["message" , '%{INT:shopID}~%{INT:userID}']
   }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "127.0.0.1:9200"
    index => "shop"
  }
}





# Set the bind address to a specific IP (IPv4 or IPv6):
#
network.host: 0.0.0.0
#
# Set a custom port for HTTP:
#
http.port: 9200
```

elasticsearch version 5.1.1 -
logstash version 2.4.0

Comment: When you log in to your ES machine (192.168.56.100) and run `curl 127.0.0.1:9200` do you get a response?

Comment: yaah I got respone sir

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any errors in logstash log? Try instead `0.0.0.0` set in elasticsearch.yml `_local_` or `127.0.0.1`. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html#network-interface-values

Comment: everything is oke, no error sir. but no data in elasticsearch